# Vue Router this.$router.push not working on methods

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I'm doing login, but after the login methods gets success, I'm pushing a route for the `$router` object and it's not working, can someone help me?

My code:

```js
doLogin(){
       this.attemptLogin({...this.user}).then(function(){
            this.$router.push('/') 
            } )
  },
```

So, the login methods execute as expected, but the callback `this.$router.push('/')` does not run.

My `attemptLogin` is an action, it's code is following:

```js
export const attemptLogin = ( {commit}, user) => {
    return http.post('login', {
        'email': user.email,
        'password': user.password
    }).then(response => {
        return commit(types.setToken, response.data)
    }).catch( e => console.log(e))
}
```

Comment: You need to return the promise from `http.post`. So it should be `return http.post(...)`.

Comment: @Bert i did it, but nothing happens.

Comment: Is there a scope issue with `this` here? I don't remember how scope works with the `() => {}` syntax. In `function() {}` syntax you'd have to `.bind(this)` to the function.

Comment: @ceejayoz i changed the `() => {}` to `function( ) {}` and now it returns a this is not defined, can you answer above how do you do this in your code?

Comment: With `function` it'd be `function() { this.$router.push('/') }.bind(this)`, but if you're getting `this` is not defined when you switch, that means the `() => {}` syntax must be setting the scope correctly already.

Comment: I have tested your code, but it no worked too.

Comment: `() => {}` binds `this` to the parent scope, so you had it correct before

Comment: If `attemptLogin` is an vuex action, you'd need to call it via `this.$store.dispatch('attemptLogin', {...this.user})`. Unless you've mapped it via `mapActions`?

Comment: @thanksd yeah, i have mapped it via mapActions.

Comment: Then this should be working. You're not getting any errors? Can you show more context of you vuex module?

Comment: @thanksd look this fiddle, is my code properly.

https://jsfiddle.net/ps1fczfu/

Comment: @thanksd i do not take any errors on developer console.

Comment: Yeah that all looks correct. Are you sure your vuex module is set up correctly and are you sure you have a route defined that "/" would resolve to?

Comment: Yeah, i'm sure. All works as expected, except this.$router.push('/');

Comment: i have changed my `this.$router.push('/')` to `this.$router.push({'name': 'home'})`, i have named routes and one of them is called `'home'`, but dont works.

Comment: So you can see that the `this.$router.push` call is made, but it's just not doing what you expect? What are you expecting and what exactly isn't happening as expected?

Comment: @thanksd no, `this.$router.push(/)` is doing nothing. it just dont do anything.

Comment: So the `then` callback for in your `doLogin` method is never firing? Or is it firing and you're expecting to be routed to "/", but the route doesn't change?

Comment: Problem solved, i've changed the `this.$router.push('/')` method for `this.$route.go('/')` and it worked. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: @thanksd the problem was the `this.$router.push()` method, idk but it just does not worked in no one of my tries.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have to push to a name or path
Try this:

```
this.$router.push({ path: '/' })
this.$router.push({ name: 'Home' })
```

Comment: No you don't. router.push(location, onComplete?, onAbort?) https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#router-push-location-oncomplete-onabort

Answer (score 28):

Solved, i changed the method `this.$router.push()` from my code, to `this.$router.go('/')`.

Thanks for everyone in comments.

Comment: but why it success do i need figure out from the documentation

Comment: I am also facing the same issue where $router.push does not work in Firefox.
Suggested $router.go did not work here as that is only to navigate by no of navigation back & forward in the browser history.

Comment: guys, i have no idea why this worked for me, but at the time, was the only way it worked.

Comment: For those that have no idea: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#router-go-n

Comment: Documentation doesn't help either, because there `This method takes a single integer as parameter that indicates by how many steps to go forwards or go backwards in the history stack...` so `.go('/')` shouldn't work. I assume that is just does a page reload and that makes it work. Besides `.go()` does the same in my case.

Comment: I succeed with adding `this.$router.go(0)` after the push (not replacing). Maybe it just needs a reload.

Answer (score 17):

In my case, I found that my `beforeRouteUpdate` does not execute `next()` method

Bad:

```js
beforeRouteUpdate(to, from, next) {
  /*
  something...
  */
}
```

Good:

```js
beforeRouteUpdate(to, from, next) {
  /*
  something...
  */

  next() // DO IT!
}
```

Comment: Oh my god, THANKS!! I know this question isn't the place to expect the `Navigation Guard` to be the problem. But this is what my problem is.

Answer (score 8):

I know this topic is a little old, but having come across this issue in particular with Nuxt & Vue I wanted to just give a little update that might help some people.

```
login() {
    this.$auth.loginWith('local', {
        data: {
            username: this.username,
            password: this.password,
        }
    });
    this.$router.push({name: 'dashboard'});
}
```

My code was originally this, but I forgot to ensure that I was either using a Promise or using an Async / Await method.

The correct code (in my case) looked like this;

```
async login() {
    await this.$auth.loginWith('local', {
        data: {
            username: this.username,
            password: this.password,
        }
    });
    this.$router.push({name: 'dashboard'});
}
```

As I said, you can use `.then()` and such if otherwise needed. But I didn't want to not put this out there to whoever might need it. Rookie mistake on my part.

Comment: Sure, you are totally right, it was not working because I was trying to push before the authentication completes. I just added the await worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue with this.$router.push('/') seemingly not working, as I got no redirect and no errors in the log. What I failed to realize was that I had a little piece of middleware that was looking if a auth token was set. I had it look in the wrong store, so naturally it would always return falls. Remember to look in your middleware if you have that, as it won't return an error on router.push()

Comment: I literally wrote my auth guard then forgot about it. Lolllll

Answer (score 3):

I don't really like the $router.go approach because it's doing a full refresh of the page.

In my case, the reason why it was not working was because I was trying to $router.push to a protected route BEFORE updating the states. *More specifically, I was dependant on Firebase onAuthStateChanged to update the states and I was trying to $router.push before this action that I had no control over. *

**Suggestions:**

- Make sure the states your middleware depend on (on your protected route) are committed before trying to push to that route.
- Push to a non protected route like 'index' and make your components reactive based on state values. (Not the best approach)

  - What I ended up doing with Firebase Auth was to create another action committing the same states my firebase onAuthStateChanged was committing but doing it myself in my async function.

Hope it helps. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Make sure you set `mode: 'history'` in the router

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can use following codes for change route in Nuxtjs.

```
this.$router.push("/");
or
this.$router.push({ path: '/'} );
```

Suppose, In case if your now viewing this link "http://localhost:3000" or "http://192.168.0.102:300" and trying to change route by push using given code to route "/". so it will not working. Because, you already viewing this route. So, Nuxtjs route cant not change.

For handling this case you can using following technique/code inside your methods:

vuejs way:

```
if($route.path == '/') {
   //following 2 line code are sample code here put your need codes
   this.isLogin = false;
   this.user_full_name = 'My Account';
} else {
   // this.$router.push("/");
   this.$router.push({ path: '/'} );
}
```

=============================================

nuxtjs way:

```
if($nuxt.$route.path == '/') {
   //following 2 line code are sample code here put your need codes
   this.isLogin = false;
   this.user_full_name = 'My Account';
} else {
   // this.$router.push("/");
   this.$router.push({ path: '/'} );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I took a copy of global `this` using `that = this` from global scope then used `that.$router.push('/path')`

And that worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

in my case i had to add the `async` keyword to the component script tag:

```
<script async setup>
```

Answer (score -2):

Before:

```
    doLogin(){
    this.attemptLogin({...this.user})
    .then(function(){
    this.$router.push('/') 
    } )
    },
```

After:

```
    doLogin(){
    this.attemptLogin({...this.user})
    .then(() => {
    this.$router.push('/') 
    } )
    },
```