# programmatic change route but view is not updating

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I have a table of data, each row has a `rowClickHandler(record)`, which has the data of the clicked row.

for example:
[image: click example]

When I click a row, I am pushing the route like this:

```js
this.$router.push(`/reports/betriebssysteme/${record.os}`);
```

and my router config for this components is this:

```js
{
    path: '/reports/betriebssysteme',
    component: OSystems,
    props: true,
    children: [
      {
        path: ':os',
        component: DoubleTable,
      },
    ],
  },
```

When I click the row, my URL changes into:
`/reports/betriebssysteme/Windows%207` the whitespace gets replaced with a `%20` and the page is not updating.

Comment: Are you using `beforeRouteUpdate`? Also, try inserting this [option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57181738/11023871). Tell me if this helps

Comment: Or try something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52982016/11023871). I think this should work